# Can't create user in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, admin

I want to create a user, which will be an admin in my `classicmodels` database. I want that my admin user can create other user accounts and assign them only to `classicmodels` database. I have already done the following steps:

1. logged as root
2. `create user admin@'%' identified by 'qwerty';`
3. `grant all privileges on classicmodels.* to admin@'%' with grant
   option;`
4. `flush privileges;`
5. Result of `show grants for admin@'%':`

GRANT USAGE ON `*.*` TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON classicmodels.* TO 'admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION

Now logged in as admin:

1. `use classicmodels;`
2. `create user user1@'%' identified by 'qwerty';`

   > ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

I don't see, where I'm doing mistake. I've given all privileges to admin in step 3, when I was logged in as root. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given all privileges for a database (schema) in specific and not globally.

Run the following queries and check the results.

```sql
SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`db` WHERE `User` = 'admin' AND `Host` = '%';
SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`user` WHERE `User` = 'admin' AND `Host` = '%';
```

> [13.7.1.2 CREATE USER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-user.html)
>
> ...
>
> ... To use this statement, you must have the global CREATE USER
>   privilege or the INSERT privilege for the mysql database. ...
>
> ...

**UPDATE**

> [13.7.1.4 GRANT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html)
>
> ...
>
> The CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE USER, FILE, PROCESS, RELOAD, REPLICATION
>   CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE, SHOW DATABASES, SHUTDOWN, and SUPER
>   privileges are administrative and can only be granted globally.
>
> ...

You need to do the following:

1. Logged as root
2. `GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%';`
3. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

```sql
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'admin'@'%';
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for admin@%                                                                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*AA1420F182E88B9E5F874F6FBE7459291E8F4601' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `classicmodels`.* TO 'admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION                                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: First query gives me Y in all columns. Second query gives N in all columns. What should I do in such case?